# Resolving issues with overdue payments for freelance work

Tags: contract-law, internet, business

A freelance client of mine is months behind in their payments and is requiring digital account access prior to paying. What are my rights?

The client doesn't read or respond to emails or phone calls.

The client recently appointed a point person for me to discuss these past due payments with. The point person requested more work prior to payment. I declined and offered a payment schedule.

The point person responded harshly, dissolving the business relationship and demanding digital web/email account access immediately prior to any payment.

Comment: Lawyer.  Lawyer lawyer lawyer.  Lawyer.

Comment: I was expecting something more helpful than chanting Lawyer five times. If I could afford a lawyer I would already have one. If it is a reasonable expectation, I hope to find an answer better than @Stackstuck's response.

Comment: There are many kinds of questions that can be answered here. Some questions however have answers that can only be provided by legal counsel that you have retained. It is likely that Stackstruck is trying to convey this with their comment.

Answer (score 4):

Law SE is not for direct legal advice. You're in the middle of a contract dispute that has turned acrimonious and need to find legal help. Google for free or low cost legal aid in your area. If this "point person" has mentioned a lawyer or made legal threats, you do need legal help.